# I misread a cider making kit, doubled the sugar

Tags: cider

I missed read a cider making kit and put 3.5 kilos of sugar in it instead of 1.7?
Could I turn this in to wine by adding a wine yest instead of cider yeast?
Or any other advice please apart from read the correct instruction?

23L of Strawberry cider

Comment: It depends one how much cider you are making.

Answer (score 2):

3.5kg of sugar in 23 liters compared to 1.7kg will add 3% abv. So the cider will be a little stronger than expected, but not a reason to panic. The yeast quantity means you have underpitched, but again no cause for alarm - the yeast will propagate to the desired level - you might get some more esters, but given that this is already a fruity brew that's probably a good thing!

So I'd leave it as is. At the most this means primary might take a few days longer, and you may need to condition for a little while longer. There are many that bump up the amount of fermentables in a kit to get a more robust abv.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use wine yeast to make strawberry cider/wine.

A Champagne Yeast and some other wine yeast have an alcohol ceiling that varies from 14% to 18%, it will ferment most of your sugar.  Once the maximum alcohol is reached, the yeast dies, and the residual sugar will remain in your cider.

I would measure the specific gravity to determine the maximum alcohol potential, then choose my wine yeast accordingly.

Comment: How do i measure the specific gravity please? I am new to brewing

Comment: An hydrometer is used to measure the specific gravity, which tells you how much sugar there is  (how much alcohol you can get from it).  You can buy one for about 10$.  It is very useful piece of equipment.

Comment: A refractometer can also be used, but is more expensive.  I prefer to use the hydrometer.

Comment: If I put Champagne Yest in it will it turn into champagne and if not how do i do it? Thank you Philippe for your answers

Comment: Every yeast strain has its own characteristics, such as alcohol tolerance, working temperature, and they also can impart some subtle flavors. They can ferment any type of cider or wine, but sometimes are more suited for a specific type.  It is not uncommon to use a champagne yeast to make cider.  If you ask your local brewstore, they will be able to help you choose the right one.

Comment: All yeasts will work, and the end results will be similar, with very small differences.  There was probably a yeast pack coming with your kit?

Answer (score 1):

Adding a different yeast does not change the type of product. Using a wine/cider/beer yeast can change the flavour, but if the base fermentable is apple juice then the drink will remain a cider.

Note: Although Ales and Lagers are different products, they are both still beers. I have used champagne yeast in a high alcohol beer that I made.

In your case, all that you will end up with is a cider with about twice the amount of alcohol that you planned. Not a train smash... usually.

Possible solutions are: (assuming you made a 21 liter batch)
1. Ferment it as is, with the cider yeast. See what it tastes like afterwards.
2. Split the amount into 2 buckets and add liters of (sanitized) water to each bucket and 5 liter of (sanitized) apple juice. Or just use 10 liters of apple juice extra in each.

Comment: Oh, and add more strawberries! :)